# Swift: ViewController Title Size in Code?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController.

I added a Title to the Viewcontroller.

Its a variable.

```
 var Title: String! = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


      self.title = Title
}
```

Is there a way, to make the font bigger?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This way you can customise your navigation title:

```
self.title = ""
var attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 20)!] //change size as per your need here.
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 1):

```
Make a Title View Label and assign it to the navigation item.
```

code for it is:

```
var tlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40))
tlabel.text = self.navigationItem.title;
tlabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
tlabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
self.navigationItem.titleView = tlabel
```

Comment: You saved my day, dude! Thanks very much!!

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the possible work around. You can assign any UIView to a navcontroller's title area.

Create a UILabel and set its font and size anyway you want, then assign it to the UIViewController's navigationItem.titleView property. Make sure the UILabel's backgroundColor is set to clearColor.

```
UILabel *labelTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero);
labelTitle.text = "Title";

labelTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Your-Font-Name", size: SIZE)

labelTitle.text.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
self.navigationItem.titleView = labelTitle;
```

Comment: I´ll try it, but i actually need it for Swift, not obj-c. Thanks anyway :D